# Chinese remainder theorem issue

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let's say I have the following equations:

$$x \equiv 2 \mod 3$$
$$x \equiv 7 \mod 10$$
$$x \equiv 10 \mod 11$$
$$x \equiv 1 \mod 7$$

And I need to find the smallest x for which all these equations are correct. So:

$N = 3\times10\times11\times7 = 2310$
$N_1 = \frac{2310}{3} = 770$
$N_2 = \frac{2310}{10} = 231$
$N_3 = \frac{2310}{11} = 210$
$N_4 = \frac{2310}{7} = 330$

Then:
$\gcd (3, 770) = 1 = 257\times3 - 1\times770; \qquad x_{1} = -1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$
$\gcd(10, 231) = 1 = -23\times10 + 1\times231; \quad x_{1} = 1$

Etc., and finally:

$x = 2\times2\times N_1 + 7\times1\times N_2 + ...$

---

I understand the whole method except for one thing - when I solved $\gcd(3, 770)$ I got $x_{1} = -1$...why is there $-1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$, from which the final result is 2?

Comment: Are you asking why $-1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$? Because that's easy to demonstrate.

Comment: Well, yes and no. I'm asking why is MOD used in places where it's not true that $x_{1} = 1$. And how 2 got there (I'm guessing mod 3 came from the 3 that stands near 257).

Comment: ahh, I see what you're saying now. You found the least common multiple of the three moduluses, but you didn't take into account the congruence. Your answer would be true if these were all $0 \mod m$.

Answer (score 2):

More simply: $ $ mod $3,11\!:\ x\equiv -1,\ $ so $ $ mod $33\!:\ x\equiv -1\ $ so $\ x = -1 + 33j.$

mod $7\!:\ 1 \equiv x \equiv -1 + 33j\ \Rightarrow\ j\equiv \frac{2}{33} \equiv \frac{2}{{-}2} \equiv -1\ $ so $\ j = -1 + 7k.$

Substituting:  $\ x = -1 + 33j = -1 + 33(-1 + 7k) = -34 + 231k.$

mod $10\!:\ 7 \equiv x \equiv -34 + 231k \equiv -4 + k\ $ so $\ k\equiv 7+4\equiv 1,\ $ i.e. $\ k = 1+10n.$

Substituting: $\ x = -34 + 231k = -34 + 231(1+10n) = 197 + 2310n.$

Answer (score 0):

What you have calculated is the LCM (least common multiple) of the moduli. However, this doesn't solve the problem, because they are all congruent to different values modulo m. For example, if the problem were as follows:

$$x \equiv b \mod 3$$
$$x \equiv b \mod 10$$
$$x \equiv b \mod 11$$
$$x \equiv b \mod 7$$

Your solution would be true if $b=0$. Similarly, if $b=1$, the solution would be $2371$.

Comment: 197? How could it fail to satisfy the relations when all the moduli are coprime?

Comment: @RobertMastragostino Because even using the LCM, there's still none that satisfy the relations, because the other number (the one to the right of the mod that I don't know the proper name of). Do you see any problems in my calculations?

Comment: I think your augmented matrix has wrong dimensions. $5 $ variables, $4$ equations, hence it should be $4\times 6$. And, btw, 197 satisfies the OP's problem. Take a look at the formulation of Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: @TZakrevskiy thanks for catching that. I removed the erroneous parts.